# How to make sure method called from taskList doesn't get executed simultaneously?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a method, that downloads a memoryStream from a cloudDrive and then passes this memoryStream to taskList which reads the file:

```
  public async Task CreateFiles(List<MyDataClass> list)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var memorySteam = await _cloudService.DownloadStreamFromCloudAsync(item);

            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (memoryStream)
                {
                    ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile(memoryStream, new MyFileSerializer());
                    readFile.DoWork();
                }
                UpdateTreeViewRecursively();

            }));
        }
    }

    public void UpdateTreeViewRecursively()
    {
        //...
        //Here I do recursive operations on a treeView. This may take a while
    }
```

The problem is that when one task has finished and file is read, I call a method that does some time consuming job and there is a possibility that this method has not been finished yet and next task is already calling it again.  Should I use lock or there are other solutions to this problem?

EDIT:
I will try to explain why I have chosen such architecture:

1) User calls CreateFiles method and downloading from cloud begins: 30 files, size varies from 1mb to 70mb. Downloading is limited to one file at a time.

2) Then each downloaded memoryStream is passed into tasks.Add(..). By doing so I would like to achieve that few files can be read at the same time and when one file is done, I call UpdateTreeViewRecursively(); This method marks treeViewItem as ready for use and also checks if all other childItems of its parent have downloaded and are ready to use.  In such a way user immediately sees which files can be used and does not have to wait until the large 70mb files are being processed to start work with program.

3) To ensure that flags in treeView are set correctly I need to make sure that UpdateTreeViewRecursively(); method is not called one more time while it is being executed by the previous caller.

Comment: Why not wait until all tasks have finished reading the file and then call the long running method 1 time? If you have to call the long running method for each task, then yes, locks would be necessary to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Does updating the tree view when only some of the files have been read make sense? Can you not update it after all the files have been read? else I wonder if putting the task on the dispatcher queue would help?

Comment: Just curious, is it required to call the UpdateTreeViewRecursively for each item in list? or can it be called once after all the tasks are completed?

Comment: Can you not just add all of your tasks in `tasks`, do an `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());` and once that is done just call `UpdateTreeViewRecursively()` once? Is calling `UpdateTreeViewRecursively()` after each file a requirement?

Comment: Thank you all for answers. Yes that is requirement to update treeView after each file has been downloaded/created.

Comment: @niks: What's the problem with calling the long-running method in thread B before it has returned in thread A...? What is the method doing?

Comment: If you need `UpdateTreeViewRecursively()` to run synchronously it seems you could  just remove the `Task.Run(...)` part? To me it seems the `await _cloudService.DownloadStreamFromCloudAsync(...)` will to block so that only one download is run at a time. Then why update the TreeView in a separate thread if doing so will cause a race condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that when one task has finished and file is read, I call a method that does some time consuming job and there is a possibility that this method has not been finished yet and next task is already calling it again. Should I use lock or there are other solutions to this problem?

Since that method is *modifying the UI thread*, then it should be run on the UI thread. So maybe something like this:

```
public async Task CreateFiles(List<MyDataClass> list)
{
  var tasks = list.Select(async item =>
  {
    using (var memorySteam = await _cloudService.DownloadStreamFromCloudAsync(item))
    {
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
        ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile(memoryStream, new MyFileSerializer());
        readFile.DoWork();
      });
    }

    UpdateTreeViewRecursively();
  });
}
```

The UI context itself acts as a "lock", so it won't run `UpdateTreeViewRecursively` concurrently.

If the "This may take a while" code degrades the user experience, then you should refactor that method so that either it can offload the slow parts to `Task.Run`, or else use `IProgress<T>` for all its UI updates and run the entire `UpdateTreeViewRecursively` method in a `Task.Run`. Examples:

```
// Approach using Task.Run within UpdateTreeViewRecursively:
public async Task UpdateTreeViewRecursively()
{
  UpdateSomeTreeViewItem();
  var data = await Task.Run(() => SomeSlowCodeThatDoesNotUpdateUI());
  UpdateSomeOtherTreeViewItem(data);
}
```

```
// Approach using IProgress<T>:
public async Task CreateFiles(List<MyDataClass> list)
{
  var tasks = list.Select(async item =>
  {
    using (var memorySteam = await _cloudService.DownloadStreamFromCloudAsync(item))
    {
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
        ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile(memoryStream, new MyFileSerializer());
        readFile.DoWork();
      });
    }

    var progress = new Progress<MyTreeViewItemUpdate>(update => UpdateSomeTreeViewItem(update));
    await Task.Run(() => UpdateTreeViewRecursively();
  });
}

public void UpdateTreeViewRecursively(IProgress<MyTreeViewItemUpdate> progress)
{
  progress?.Report(new MyTreeViewItemUpdate() { ... });
  var data = SomeSlowCodeThatDoesNotUpdateUI();
  progress?.Report(new MyTreeViewItemUpdate() { ... = data... });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Hmm, I didn't think of it in a way that UI context can be used as a "lock" itself. I would like to clarify one silly thing - if I call UpdateTreeViewRecursively method from UI thread, lets say 400 times in one second, all the calls will line up and just wait their turn to execute one by one? I have made a small test and yes, indeed, all the calls get executed, but maybe there is something that I haven't thought about that must be taken into account?

Comment: @niks: All code on the UI thread runs exclusively - one after another. The code does have to be *running* for this to be true; if a method `await`s, then other code can run on the UI thread while it's awaiting.

Answer (score 0):

Either use locks or use  .Result on the Task.Run method to await the result from the task. That way your main thread will wait till your task is completed.